# R studio project coding issues; math.data.frame (error)

Tags: r

so recently I've been working through an R project and have struggled continuously. I am just wondering if there is someone who could give me a hand please. I need the returns column from a data set; I will attach said code below, and I keep getting the same error. I am not very advanced with R so I am wondering where my error is.

```
#Calculating daily returns
library(quantmod)
data.frame(SharePriceAnalysis)%>%
  head(cbind(SharePriceAnalysis), 6)%>%
class(SharePriceAnalysis)%>%
date.index = index(SharePriceAnalysis)%>%
head(date.index, 6)%>%
class(date.index)%>%
as.numeric(date.index[1])%>%
SharePriceAnalysis["Jack Warnes (20554451)"]%>%
SharePriceAnalysisLogPrices= log(SharePriceAnalysis)
  head(SharePriceAnalysis, 6)
```

This then gives me the following message;

```
Error in Math.data.frame(SharePriceAnalysis) : 
non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: symbol, date
2.
stop("non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: ", paste(vnames[!mode.ok], 
collapse = ", "))
1.
Math.data.frame(SharePriceAnalysis)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: well you can't do math operations on data frames with non numeric, logical, or complex variables as the error suggests, so `log(SharePriceAnalysis)` would fail if you had symbols and dates which it seems you do. but none of this code makes sense to me, so I'm surprised you even got to that error, for example you have `head(mtcars) %>% class(mtcars) %>% date.index = ...` which not only doesnt make sense but should be a couple syntax errors

Comment: What is `cbind(SharePriceAnalysis)` supposed to do? `cbind` puts together vector or tables column by column. Here you only have one object.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses I do appreciate it. I have very limited R knowledge and experience, I've been trying to teach myself so I can finish an assignment. Most of that code is what I have learnt from forums, so I am unsure of what I am doing. However, my aim is to calculate the daily returns from an imported data set in a previous chunk, then create a new column on a data set that expresses these returns.